# How can I display video when a marker is detected in unity android artoolkit?

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I want to display a video when a marker is detected. I am working in unity and coding for android. Please help.

Comment: Please add a bit more effort in asking questions, you get these down votes for a reason... You could give us some informations : Which implementation are you using for marker detection? Are you using Unity or just Android Java? What exactly did you try to accomplish your goal and didn't work obviously?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that the current [MovieTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html) of Unity does not support mobile playback (It's on their roadmap to upgrade this).
But there are some options you can check, either there are a lot of plugins which implement your wanted functionality, but most of them are not for free. 
Or you go the easy way and check the download section from Vuforia, because they got an example which implements exactly your wanted functionality :

https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples

Answer (score 0):

I used Easy Movie Texture Plugin to play Video in Unity. Its working as I needed.